# Is it possible to have an SMTP login without a username, but with a password?

Tags: smtp

Sometimes, users of our software, which connects to SMTP servers, put in a password, but no username.  (Or, rather, their browsers' autocomplete specifies a password, but no username.)

Is there any valid SMTP configuration that has a password and no username?  Are we safe in ignoring any password when there is no username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any valid SMTP configuration that has a password and no username?

No. Theoretically, someone could code up an SMTP server that allowed this for some wacky reason, but I'm not aware of it existing.

> Are we safe in ignoring any password when there is no username?

Yes.

Good luck,

--jed